# DWARF reading not complete types

Tags: c++, dwarf

How can I read a non complete types in DWARF dumps?

For example we have a derived class:

```
class Base
{
    public:
        int Base_var1;
        int Base_var2;
    ....
}

class OtherClass : public Base
{
    int OtherClass_var1;
    int OtherClass_var2;
    ....
}

OtherClass otherClass();
```

We compile this with GCC compiler and want to find all members of `otherClass` object. We get the next DWARF dump:

```
<1><20a>: Abbrev Number: 15 (DW_TAG_variable)
   <20b>   DW_AT_name        : otherClass
   <211>   DW_AT_type        : <0x131>  

<1><131>: Abbrev Number: 117 (DW_TAG_class_type)
   <132>   DW_AT_name        : OtherClass
   <133>   DW_AT_declaration : 1    
   <134>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x150>  
<2><135>: Abbrev Number: 45 (DW_TAG_member)
   <136>   DW_AT_name        : OtherClass_var1  
   <137>   DW_AT_type        : <0x12>   
   <138>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 2 byte block: 23 8   (DW_OP_plus_uconst: 8)
 ......
```

We have a variable `otherClass`, which have a type of `0x131`. This type have `DW_AT_declaration` flag, which means that this is non complete type. Type at `0x131` have all members of it's main class (`OtherClass_var1` and `OtherClass_var2`), but don't have any information about derived members.

If continue reading DWARF dump, then in some place we get this:

```
<1><500>: Abbrev Number: 150 (DW_TAG_class_type)
   <501>   DW_AT_specification: <0x131> 
   <502>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 2696 
   <503>   DW_AT_containing_type: <0x560>   
   <504>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0x36078>    
<2><135>: Abbrev Number: 45 (DW_TAG_member)
   <136>   DW_AT_name        : Base_var1    
   <137>   DW_AT_type        : <0x12>   
   <138>   DW_AT_data_member_location: 2 byte block: 23 8 
.....
```

There is a definition for our base class and this definition have `DW_AT_specification` tag, which shows where to find a other part of this class (main part).

How can we correctly read this `otherClass` object? At this moment I have to store array of all types and when I get a `DW_AT_declaration` tag, I should go through array and find a type with specification to this type.

And how can I get a absolute address of derived members? We have a absolute address of variable `otherClass`. Then member `OtherClass_var1` would have the same address as `otherClass`. Member `OtherClass_var2` would have address of `OtherClass_var1` plus a byte size of `OtherClass_var1`. But how can we calculate the address of derived members `Base_var1` and `Base_var2`?